# Quasar / Capacitor error: ".../node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index has no exported member 'Config'"

Tags: typescript, webpack, quasar-framework

When I build my app with:

```
quasar build -m capacitor -T ios
```

I now get the following errors:

/Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts
ERROR in /Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts(30,53):

TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index"' has no exported member 'Config'.

/Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts
ERROR in /Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts(36,29):

TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/myusername/Documents/my-app-name/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index"' has no exported member 'Config'.

Any references to this kind of error that I can find online describe situations that do not seem to be related to my own.

The last time I built my app (about a 3-4 weeks ago), it built just fine.

I have tried deleting all of the following and rebuilding:

```
node_modules
src_capacitor
package-lock.json
yarn.lock
```

Running quasar info command yields the following:

```
Operating System - Darwin(19.6.0) - darwin/x64
NodeJs - 12.18.3

Global packages
  NPM - 6.14.9
  yarn - 1.22.5
  @quasar/cli - 1.1.2
  @quasar/icongenie - 2.3.3
  cordova - 10.0.0

Important local packages
  quasar - 1.14.5 -- Build high-performance VueJS user interfaces (SPA, PWA, SSR, Mobile and Desktop) in record time
  @quasar/app - 2.1.8 -- Quasar Framework local CLI
  @quasar/extras - 1.9.10 -- Quasar Framework fonts, icons and animations
  eslint-plugin-quasar - Not installed
  vue - 2.6.12 -- Reactive, component-oriented view layer for modern web interfaces.
  vue-router - 3.2.0 -- Official router for Vue.js 2
  vuex - 3.6.0 -- state management for Vue.js
  electron - 10.1.6 -- Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS
  electron-packager - 14.2.1 -- Customize and package your Electron app with OS-specific bundles (.app, .exe, etc.) via JS or CLI
  electron-builder - 22.9.1 -- A complete solution to package and build a ready for distribution Electron app for MacOS, Windows and Linux with “auto update” support out of the box
  @babel/core - 7.12.9 -- Babel compiler core.
  webpack - 4.44.2 -- Packs CommonJs/AMD modules for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand. Support loaders to preprocess files, i.e. json, jsx, es7, css, less, ... and your custom stuff.
  webpack-dev-server - 3.11.0 -- Serves a webpack app. Updates the browser on changes.
  workbox-webpack-plugin - 5.1.4 -- A plugin for your Webpack build process, helping you generate a manifest of local files that workbox-sw should precache.
  register-service-worker - 1.7.1 -- Script for registering service worker, with hooks
  typescript - 3.9.5 -- TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development
  @capacitor/core - 2.4.3 -- Capacitor: cross-platform mobile apps with the web
  @capacitor/cli - 2.4.3 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/android - 2.4.3 -- Capacitor: cross-platform mobile apps with the web
  @capacitor/ios - 2.4.3 -- Capacitor: cross-platform mobile apps with the web

Quasar App Extensions
  @quasar/quasar-app-extension-qmediaplayer - 1.1.3 -- A Quasar App Extension for @quasar/quasar-ui-qmediaplayer

Networking
  Host - MacBook-Pro-3.local
  en1 - 10.0.0.143
```

Can anyone help?

** Additional note: I get the same errors if I try to build with Cordova instead.

Comment: I never did find the answer to my question. I ended up having to delete the entire project, create a new quasar project with the same name from scratch, and restore the src and public folders along with quasar.conf.js file. This cleared the error for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

adding "skipLibCheck": true in the tsconfig.json file solved the issue
my tsconfig.json looks like this now:

```
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```